# SQL Counting empy fields in a row

Tags: sql, sas

I'm new to SQL and i'm not sure what i want to do is possible.

Basically i want to count the number of empty fields present in a row and add it as a column at the end, like so:
Original data

| ID | Code | Name | Age |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | aaa | name1 | 23 |
| 1111 | bbb | name1 | 23 |
| 2222 | cccc |  |  |
| 3333 | fdfd |  | 34 |
| 3333 | rrrr |  |  |

Result:

| ID | Code | Name | Age | Empty Fields |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | aaa | name1 | 23 | 0 |
| 1111 | bbb | name1 | 23 | 0 |
| 2222 | cccc |  |  | 2 |
| 3333 | fdfd |  | 34 | 1 |
| 3333 | rrrr |  |  | 2 |

After that i want to concatenate the code field for each duplicate ID and delete the line with the  higher Empty fields, like so:

Result:

First:

| ID | Code | Name | Age | Empty Fields |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | aaa,bbb | name1 | 23 | 0 |
| 1111 | aaa,bbb | name1 | 23 | 0 |
| 2222 | cccc |  |  | 2 |
| 3333 | fdfd,rrrr |  | 34 | 1 |
| 3333 | rrrr,fdfd |  |  | 2 |

End Result:

| ID | Code | Name | Age | Empty Fields |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1111 | aaa,bbb | name1 | 23 | 0 |
| 2222 | cccc |  |  | 2 |
| 3333 | fdfd,rrrr |  | 34 | 1 |

Comment: I can't tell what your question is.  You seem to have multiple questions here.

Comment: I want to know how to code the examples i've made, sry if i haven't explained well enough

Comment: Why do you want to know how to do it with SQL?  Why not just write normal SAS code?

Answer (score 0):

This is an inefficient method/logic but since you've laid out your steps I assume there's some reason for this logic.

1. Count the Number of Missing using CMISS which counts across character and numeric variables. Set the variable to 0 initially so it's not included in the missing count. Use `_all_` to refer to all variables in the data set.

```
*calculate number missing;
data step1;
set have;
*set N_Missing to 0 so it is not counted as missing;
N_Missing = 0;
*count missing;
N_Missing =  cmiss(Of _all_);
run;
```

2. Combine CODE into one field, using a data step.

```
*combine CODE from into one field;
proc sort data=step1;
by id code;
run;


data step2;
set have;
by ID code;

retain Code_Agg;
length Code_Agg $80.;

if first.ID then Code_Agg = Code;
else Code_Agg = catx(", ", Code_Agg, Code);

if last.ID then output;

keep ID Code_AGG;

run;
```

3. Merge output from #1 and #2 to get the middle table. You may need to sort the data ahead of time.

```
*merge results with prior table;
data step3;
merge step1 step2;
by ID;
run;
```

4. Keep record only of interest using NODUPKEY in PROC SORT which keeps only unique record. Note the double sort, first sorting to get the order correct to take the first record.

```
proc sort data=step3;
by ID N_Missing;
run;

proc sort data=step3 out=final nodupkey;
by ID;
run;
```